# How to run Internet Explorer in background with VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, background-process, background-task

I want to run Internet Explorer in background. I used this script and IE is opened but it's a visible window and not run in background.

```
On Error Resume Next

'Declare a new variable or array variable
Dim ie 

'Create an InternetExplorer Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'Set objExplorer.Visible = True to make IE visible, or False for IE to run in the background
ie.Visible = False

'Navigate to Defined URL
ie.Navigate "http://localhost:9090/csv_reader/csv.php"

'Perform IE functions here......
If err.number <> 0 then wscript.echo err.number & ":" & err.description
```

I found this script on this platform. I tried but couldn't get a proper result. Can anyone correct this script and suggest to me how to solve it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. The code you show does hide the IE window it opens, nothing is shown. Either you do not use exactly the code in your question or the issue is not your code but something else. • In which application (Excel, Word, …) do you use this code?

Comment: I try to check your sample code and the code looks fine. `ie.Visible = False` working correctly and the IE browser does not get visible. I suggest close all existing IE windows and then try to run the above code sample. Check whether it works properly or not.

Comment: yes, I used this code as a .VBA file, IE not run in background @Pᴇʜ Thank you for reply

Comment: yeah sir i will check as you suggest me @Deepak-MSFT    Thank you

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT   sir it's not working in the background, IE gets open in desktop

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT   sir IE gets open on the desktop, IE is visible.  please suggest me about it so I could run IE in the background, and also suggest me for minimized running IE through code.

Comment: `.VBA` files? What are you doing **exactly**? VBA files don't exist. VBA means *"Visual Basic for Applications"* and needs to be run in an Office application like Excel or Word. You cannot run VBA stand alone. Or do you mean `.vbs`? But this is VBScript then and is not the same as VBA. Note that even if I run your code as VBScript it does not show an IE window. Your issue is not reproduceable (see also [mcve]), therefore the issue is not in the code.

Comment: As other community members had already informed you about the .VBA files. I suggest you if you are available with the Office app like Excel then open it and try to launch the Visual basic from the developer tab. Try to paste this [sample code](https://freetexthost.net/QkygriYF) there and try to run it. It may help you to get the desired result.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ    Thank you.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thank you sir.

Comment: @user14448790, let us know about the status of the issue. if the issue still persists then we can try to provide further suggestions. thanks for your understanding.